# Collection of short stories about plane flight to the future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Back in 2017, I read a collection of short stories on a website, all around a single theme (similar to Machine of Death, I believe). The theme was a plane flight that went into the future. I think it was to a specific date, 2030 or 2050.

It started off with a single intro, but everyone's take on the elements that came after were different. I don't remember much about the specific stories, but some were optimistic, some were dystopian, and overall it was a pretty interesting collection.

The website interface was a seat selection cutaway of an aeroplane, like one would see at the airport. Not every seat was filled, but each seat that was highlighted was a different story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Past googling returned no results, but further research has returned [Seat 14C](http://seat14c.com/)! Unfortunately, the https version of the website seems to be broken at the present date (April 2020). Here's a summary of the competition from [Wired](https://www.wired.com/beyond-the-beyond/2017/06/seat-14c-jets-future/)

> Today, ANA, Japan’s five-star airline, and XPRIZE, the global leader in incentivize price competitions, launched campaign Seat 14C, a digital anthology that blends original science fiction stories with a writing competition set 20 years in the future.
>
> ANA is asking the public to submit stories imagining the year 2037 when an ANA flight from Tokyo to San Francisco mysteriously lands in the future. The winner of the competition will win a grand prize package worth $10,000 including roundtrip airfare to Tokyo for two.

Comment: It looks like the Wayback Machine captured snapshots of the site at https://web.archive.org/web/20170701000000*/http://seat14c.com/